# Как сделать из select радио кнопки?

Tags: html, asp

Итак есть форма в скрипте.asp с выпадающем select "summa" и option "100, 200, 400" принимает форму `if($_POST['summa'] == '100')` и так далее...

Пример формы

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
                                <select name=\"summa\">
                                <option value=\"100\">100</option>
                                <option value=\"200\">200</option>
                                <option value=\"400\">400</option>
                                </select><br/>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

**Нужно:** из выпадающей сделать радио кнопки, чтобы данные "summa и 100, 200, 400" обрабатывались???

Comment: а селект это не одно и тоже что и радио? у вас же не мульти-селект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form action="form.php" method="post">

  <input type="radio" name="summa" value="100">100
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="summa" value="200">200
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="summa" value="400">400
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```